# SparkSql and REGEX

Tags: java, json, regex, apache-spark-sql

in my case i use a dataset(dataframe) in JavaSparkSQL.
This dataset result from an JSON file. The json file is formed from key-value.When i lunch a query for see the value i write for examle:

```
 SELECT key1.name from table
```

example JSON file

```
 {
     "key1":
           { "name": ".....",....}
     "key2":
           { "name":"....",....}
    }
```

my question is, when i want acceding at all key,I believe I should use a REGEX like

```
select key*.name from table
```

but i don't know the regex!
please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid no such syntax is available in (spark) SQL.

You may want to construct your query programmatically though.

Something like :

```
String sql = Stream.of(ds.schema().fieldNames()).filter(name -> name.startsWith("key")).collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "select ", " from table"));
System.out.println(sql);
```

or even

```
Dataset<Row> result = spark.table("table").select(Stream.of(ds.schema().fieldNames()).filter(name -> name.startsWith("key")).map(name -> ds.col(name))
                .toArray(Column[]::new));
result.show();
```

HTH!